# Command line with php-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm

How to run command line with a php-fpm? I can run :

```
php /home/some_script.php
```

But it runs the last version of php. I have several versions installed and configured for each virtualhost, I need to make crontabs command line to run php script but not with same php version... Is there a command line like :

```
php5.6-fpm /home/some-script.php
```

?

Answer (score 1):

specify the full path to the php5.6-fpm binary:

```
/full/path/to/php5.6-fpm /home/some-script.php
```

to find outh what the full path is you could try:

```
which php5-6.fpm
```

or use find (something like this should work):

```
find / -type f -iname php5-6.fpm
```

Comment: Ok, found it : just like that : "php5.6 /home/some-script.php"!

Comment: it can be so easy sometimes ;-)